# When converting string 4.0 or any 0.0 to float, in PHP, it becomes a whole number. Is there a way to keep the decimal place?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I have got the following code:

```php
$strNumber = "4.0";
$float = 4.0;
```

I am aiming to print the sum the two variables above and get `8.0` but weirdly when converting `$strNumber` to a float, it prints `4`. The same holds true to `$float` - when vardumping it prints 4. As result, I have in the end `8`, instead. I researched for hours for a solution but I was not successful.

I guess I could do `print_r((float)$strNumber + $float . ".0";` , though, those variables will change and so it will give me an unwanted outcome. Is there actually a solution? I would very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What's the exact problem here? How did you convert `$strNumber` to a float? How did you print it out afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sum is not, in fact, becoming a whole number.  It is only being displayed that way.  PHP has very flexible and intuitive type-casting.  By putting (float) in front of the string, you can cast it to that type.

```
$strNumber = "4.0";
$floatNumber = (float)$strNumber;
$float = 4.0;
$sum = $floatNumber + $float;
print_r(number_format($sum, 1, '.', ','));
```

However, this is not necessary at all as the casting is so automatic in PHP that the following is the same thing:

```
$strNumber = "4.0";
$float = 4.0;
$sum = $strNumber + $float;
print_r(number_format($sum, 1, '.', ','));
```

Bottom line, even if you type-cast "4.0" to (float), it's still going print "4" because that's a matter of how it prints, not the data type.  Use number_format() to make it look the way you want.

See here for more:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: `number_format()` returns a string as oppose to  a float. Plus, the variables are given to me, I have no control to set them (my fault, I didn't explain it above).

Comment: Why does that matter if the issue is having it look right for printing?  "I am aiming to print the sum the two variables..."

Comment: I've updated my answer according what I think you're getting at.

Comment: @AdamWinter, you are absolutely right. Thanks, a lot for your time.